# Cardinality of the set of all numbers in [0, 1] with decimal expansions ending in infinite sequence of 5's

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My idea is this:

Let $T$ denote the set in question.

Some typical elements of $T$ will be:

$T_1 = a_{11}a_{12}...a_{1n}555...$    ,   $n$ a natural number
$T_2 = a_{21}a_{22}...a_{2n}555...$

and so on (I'm assuming there are infinitely many elements in T, but I'm actually not certain this is correct and  I wouldn't mind a proof either way).

Define a bijection $f$ by $f:\Bbb N \to T$ by $f$($b_{11}b_{12}...b_{1n}$) $= 0.b_{11}b_{12}...b_{1n}555...$

Now I think this is kind of sketchy, especially how I "tack on" the infinite sequence of $5$'s in the definition of my bijection. Legal? Why/why not?

Comment: That seems like a fair bijection candidate. You just need to show it's really bijective (note: it's not, but it's close).

Comment: Well your map is not a bijection, since integers $5,\, 55,\, 555$, etc would all be mapped to $5/9$. Do you have to construct a bijection, or can use use other methods, like knowing cardinalitites of common sets?

Comment: @pjs36 Good point. And, can use other methods. I'm struggling with proving that something *can't* be done. The only proof in this form I've seen is Cantor's diagonal argument, and I'm struggling to see how/if that  or something similar could be argued here.

Comment: @pjs36 Of course |$\Bbb N$| $\le$  |$T$| $\le$ |[0, 1]| = c. But assuming we apply Cantor's diagonal argument to show $T$ is uncountable, there would still be the problem of defining a bijection between $T$ and $[0, 1]$.

Comment: While your latest comment is true, the fact I have in mind is that a number is rational iff it has a terminating/repeating decimal representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map is *almost* an injection. A map like this will have a hard time hitting all of $T$ though, because of the presence of leading $0$'s.

I'm suggesting that things in $T$ are all *rational*, because they all have repeating decimal representations. $$$$

In particular, since $0.555\ldots = \frac59$, you can show that $$0.d_1d_2\ldots d_{n-1}d_n5555\ldots = \dfrac{d_1d_2\ldots d_{n-1}d_n}{10^n} + \dfrac{5}{9\cdot 10^n} = \dfrac{9d_1d_2\ldots d_{n-1}d_n + 5}{9\cdot 10^n}\in \Bbb Q.$$

If you know that all countably infinite sets have the same size and can show your set $T$ is indeed infinite, you're done.

---

Modifying your map into a bijection is annoyingly tricky. As mentioned, naturals of the form $55\ldots55$ all get sent to $0.5555\ldots \in T$. Even then, the map

\begin{align*}
f : \Bbb N &\to T\\
d_1d_2\ldots d_{n-1}d_n &\mapsto 0.d_1d_2\ldots d_{n-1}d_n555\ldots
\end{align*}

will never hit anything with two or more leading $0$s (even a single leading $0$, if your $\Bbb N$ doesn't contain $0$).

You could find a way to send integers of the form $55\ldots55$ to decimals of the form $0.00\ldots00555\ldots$. There are still things in $T$ with leading $0$s left out by this map; $0.000123555\ldots$ for example. It's injective now, but I'm having a hard time modifying it to be surjective.

I love a good bijection as much as the next guy, but I personally would file this one under the "too much trouble" category.

Comment: i really like this, but is there an easy way to show that $T$ is not finite? We have the upper bound as determined by the fact that it is a subset of the rationals, but we need the lower bound. If that was established of course the result would easily follow. But I'm having trouble even *injecting* the naturals into $T$.